# Why can't I "require" react-dom.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I try to bring ReactDOM to my Jest tests. Like this.

```
const React = require('../src/js/vendor/react/build/react.js');
const ReactDOM = require('../src/js/vendor/react/build/react-dom.js');
```

When I log ReactDOM in my test, I get undefined. Why?

The path is correct. I can 'require' React.

Comment: Are you positive on the path being valid? What does your dev tool network tab say? Are you getting any 404s?

Comment: @War10ck Either the path is valid or I am losing my mind. Hard to tell about network tab, the Jest tests are ran in Node. No 404

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. Unfortunately that's out of my realm. I'm not familiar enough with Jest or Node to know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [`react-dom` source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/vendor/react-dom.js) you will see CommonJS `require` and AMD style `define` calls referencing `"react"` (where it merely wraps private API stuff for the sake of future separation), which only works if your environment is either a bundler (e.g. webpack/browserify) that understands npm path resolution or an AMD loader (e.g. requirejs) configured with a mapping for paths to modules.

Answer (score 0):

Add [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) to your project and so you can use `require(...)` on client-side

or

Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to transpire the scripts from ES5 to ES6

Answer (score -1):

The part that he's not mentioning (he's in IRC too) is that he doesn't have NPM, and that his team "decided not to use NPM"